# Show a page in VB you are not authorized

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have following function:

in a.aspx.vb page:

```
If  a = True Then
    'do something
Else
    'i want to show a not authorized page here
End If
```

Will i have to create a new page and give the url under else to show not authorized page? 
Or is there any other pre-built way to do this in .net 4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just put in a redirect to the 'error' page.

```
If  a = True Then
    'do something
Else
    'i want to show a not authorized page here, this page would reside in the root of the site, so if http://domainname.com/Not_Authorized.aspx then enter it as  Response.redirect("Not_Authorized.aspx") 

     Response.redirect("Not_Authorized.aspx") 
End If
```

Comment: do i have to create Not_Authorized.aspx page?

Comment: @NoviceMe-Yes you need to create an unauthorized page (ie.. an error page) where users if they are not authenticated you can redirect them to that page.

Comment: @NoviceMe as per DotNetter, you need a page if you want them to do something on it.  Of course you could put a redirect back to the home page and in a session variable update a Label on that page with the error message.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
If a=true then
response.redirect("/Default.aspx")
Else
response.redirect("/ErrorPage.aspx")
End If
```